# Empty interfaces to access struct properties to avoid code duplication

Tags: go

I have 2 different API versions, I'm trying to refactor code to avoid duplication.
In my method I can receive an object from V1 or V2 (which have same properties).
and I want to access those properties, currently I'm getting the following Error:

```
i.name undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)
```

```
package main

import "fmt"

type V1 struct {
  name string
  age int
  address string
}

type V2 struct {
  name string
  age int  
}


func main() {
    v1 := &V1{name: "Susan", age: 15}
    describe(v1)
    
    v2 := &V2{name: "John", age: 21}
    describe(v2)    
}

func describe(i interface{}) error {
    fmt.Printf("(%v, %T)\n", i, i)
    switch v := i.(type) {
    default:    
           return fmt.Errorf("Error detected, unexpected type %T", v)       
    case *V1:
        fmt.Println("*V1")
        i = i.(*V1)     
    case *V2:
        fmt.Println("*V2")
        i = i.(*V2)
    }
    fmt.Println(i.name)
    return nil
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   switch v := i.(type) {
    default:    
           return fmt.Errorf("Error detected, unexpected type %T", v)       
    case *V1:
        fmt.Println("*V1")
        fmt.Println(v.name)
    case *V2:
        fmt.Println("*V2")
        // v is of type *V2 here
    }
```

`v` is already of the type you need. When you reassign `i`, you are back to an `interface{}`.

Comment: Thanks, how can I access v outside the switch ? what may be the variable type I need to declare?

Comment: `v` is of the correct type variable under the matching case. It is not accessible outside the switch.

Comment: @gogasca why? Outside the switch you have `i`

Comment: I can't access i.name like in here: fmt.Println(i.name) (just edited original question)

Comment: @gogasca you cannot indeed, but outside the switch you don't know what type `v` would have been either.

Comment: Write your version/struct specific code under the matching case. Yes, you'll need to repeat things. If you have commonalities, consider embedding the smaller struct in the larger one, and use methods.

Comment: Do you think reflection may be worth exploring?

Comment: @gogasca it depends. In general - yes. For this problem - no.

Answer (score 1):

`i` variable is of `interface{}` type, you should use `v` instead, it's already of a correct `*V1` type: `v.name`

References:

- https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches